# will php/apache ever support multi threading?

Tags: java, php

i mainly focus on the web, i think i will never create desktop applications.

so i think it's better for me to focus on typical web languages like php.

i know an advantage java has over php is multi threading though.

will php ever support this feature in the future?

thanks

Comment: @Entendu: So that you could multi-thread intensive jobs...?

Comment: @Entendu: Probably... but still :p I've tapped out on my 30-second server limit with a PHP script before. I probably shouldn't have written the script in PHP, but my shared web server didn't give me many options.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Technically, Apache does support multithreading with its workers. However, PHP does not appear to be introducing better threading support in PHP 6, so you shouldn't count on it.

See [this mailing list post](http://readlist.com/lists/lists.php.net/php-general/0/1069.html) for the source.

Answer (score 3):

The better question to ask is why you would possibly need more than one thread to service a single HTTP request.

Comment: @fayer, Comet is more than a single http request.

Comment: @Earlz: how is this a better question than the one proposed? can you please explain?